# How to run translate after training the model?

Tags: tensorflow

having run this code from :

```
cd tensorflow/models/rnn/translate
python translate.py --data_dir [your_data_directory]
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html#sequence-to-sequence-models

The link above states 'takes about 20GB of disk space' so it appears like it successfully ran. My data dir is approx 20GB in size :

```
ls -l --block-size=M
total 20361M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    21M Sep  9 08:31 dev-v2.tgz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  3615M Sep  9 08:21 giga-fren.release2.en
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  1158M Sep  9 08:06 giga-fren.release2.en.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1   1001 27385 1158M Aug 30 15:55 giga-fren.release2.fixed.en.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1   1001 27385 1317M Aug 29 17:43 giga-fren.release2.fixed.fr.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  4354M Sep  9 08:19 giga-fren.release2.fr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  1317M Sep  9 08:07 giga-fren.release2.fr.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  2270M Sep  9 10:59 giga-fren.release2.ids40000.en
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  2676M Sep  9 10:24 giga-fren.release2.ids40000.fr
-rw-r--r-- 1 331729 10000    1M Dec 13  2013 newstest2013.en
-rw-r--r-- 1 331729 10000    1M Dec 13  2013 newstest2013.fr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     1M Sep  9 10:59 newstest2013.ids40000.en
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     1M Sep  9 10:59 newstest2013.ids40000.fr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  2475M Sep  9 08:08 training-giga-fren.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     1M Sep  9 09:43 vocab40000.en
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     1M Sep  9 09:11 vocab40000.fr
```

Is this just a preliminary step to running the model ?

How to use this model to test the translation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you've trained the model long enough to get a saved checkpoint (every 200 training steps by default)

Then, run `translate.py` with the `--decode` option:

```
python translate.py --data_dir [your_data_directory] --decode
```

Then it will give you a prompt to type in a source sentence, and it will emit the target sentence:

```
> hello
Bonjour
> how are you ?
Comment allez-vous ?
```

See the `decode()` function in [translate.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py) for reference...

Comment: when training completes is this your final output : ? : reading data line 15000000
  reading data line 15100000
  reading data line 15200000
Killed

Comment: no, the script will keep training until you kill the process by hand...translation can take days/weeks to train on GPU/CPU to get accurate results...you will see lines like this as the model learns: "global step XXX learning rate 0.YYYY step-time ZZ.ZZ perplexity QQ.QQ"

Comment: ok, I'm seeing 'Killed' after with no manual input. The machine I'm using for training may not be powerful enough.

Comment: agreed. you are running out of memory when loading the data set, not even getting to initializing a model, training, and checkpoints yet. need more RAM, smaller data, or re-code not load entire dataset into memory.